# DRF api filtering room that has not reservation

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

i have this scenario. User will reserve room in date range(E.g from 2017-06-08 - to 2017-07-09) Also user can choose private room or shared room. The thing is shared room should be in date range so that user can choose shared room with someone. Now i am doing queryset function with this

```
class Room(models.Model):
    number = models.CharField(max_length=8, null=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(RoomCategory, related_name="rooms")
    beds = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    size = models.CharField(max_length=2, blank=True)
    bed = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    toilet = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    guest_section = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    building_type = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    tv = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    wifi = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    shower = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    heat = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    fridge = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    microwave = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    wardrobe = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    sofa = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    towel = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    liquid_soap = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    socket = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    sun_side_window = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    block = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.number



class Reservation(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    transport_type = models.CharField(max_length=8, blank=True)
    start_date = models.DateField(null=True)
    end_date = models.DateField(null=True)
    total_days = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    arrival_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    customer_count = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="zahialagch")
    service = models.ForeignKey(Service, related_name="reservation_services", null=True, blank=True, editable=False)
    room = models.ForeignKey(Room, related_name="reservations")
    bus_seat_departure = models.ForeignKey(BusSeat, related_name="reservation_bus_seat_dep", null=True, blank=True)
    bus_seat_arrival = models.ForeignKey(BusSeat, related_name="reservations_bus_seat_arr", null=True, blank=True)
    total_payment = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    total_paid = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    reservation_group = models.ForeignKey(ReservationGroup, related_name="reservation_groups", null=True)
    # reservation_serial = models.CharField(max_length=10, default=zerofill, editable=False, verbose_name=u"Захиалгын дугаар")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s %s" % (self.created_at, self.user.username)
```

`queryset = Room.objects.filter(reservations__start_date__range=['2017-06-01', '2017-09-09])`
this returns only rooms that has reservations. How do i filter room that has not reservation(possible to reserve)?

### UPDATE

My doing is online room reservation. for some definite time user will reserve room. During that time room must not be available to reserve right. So i wonder my query method or approach is right or wrong?, here need some experience though

Comment: Room.objects.exclude

Comment: The thing is i wonder is this right approach to filter room that is available for reservation?

Comment: Room.objects.exclude(reservations__start_date__range=...) - retrieve all records, which are not in desired range.
I think it what you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
queryset = Room.objects.filter(reservations__start_date__isnull=True)
```

Comment: Although this may answer the question, some comments and/or explanation would be nice. That will help other users as well.